# Solidity - Error: Identifier not found or not unique. Compilation error

Tags: compilation, solidity

I had tried to compile this code by Compiler version 0.5.12, but I had an exception:

> browser/Untitled.sol:21:24: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
>
> function getRoleOf(adress ad) public returns(string txt){
>
> ^----^

My code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.5.13;
contract Max{
    mapping(address => uint256) private balaces;
    mapping(address => role) private roles;
    enum role{
        Admin,
        Manager,
        User
    }
    
    constructor() public{
        balaces[msg.sender] = 1000;
        roles[msg.sender] = role.Admin;
    }
    
    function getRoleOf(adress ad) public returns(string txt){
        if(roles[ad] == role.User){
            txt = "User";
            return;
        }
        if(roles[ad] == role.Manager){
            txt = "Manager";
            return;
        }
        if(roles[ad] == role.Admin){
            txt = "Admin";
            return;
        }
        return "Нет такого пользователя";
    }
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above answer(by @abcoathup) works with 0.4.26, if you want to execute your code in solidity version 0.5.12 check following code(with minor optimisation)

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.5.13;
contract Max{
    mapping(address => uint256) private balaces;
    mapping(address => role) private roles;
    enum role{
        Admin,
        Manager,
        User
    }

    constructor() public{
        balaces[msg.sender] = 1000;
        roles[msg.sender] = role.Admin;
    }

    function getRoleOf(address ad) public returns(string memory txt){
        txt = "Нет такого пользователя";
        if(roles[ad] == role.User){
            txt = "User";
        } else if(roles[ad] == role.Manager){
            txt = "Manager";
        } else if(roles[ad] == role.Admin){
            txt = "Admin";
        }
        return txt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in :`function getRoleOf(adress ad)`
`adress` should be `address`

The following compiles in Remix using Solidity Compiler 0.4.26

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.5.13;
contract Max{
    mapping(address => uint256) private balaces;
    mapping(address => role) private roles;
    enum role{
        Admin,
        Manager,
        User
    }

    constructor() public{
        balaces[msg.sender] = 1000;
        roles[msg.sender] = role.Admin;
    }

    function getRoleOf(address ad) public returns(string txt){
        if(roles[ad] == role.User){
            txt = "User";
            return;
        }
        if(roles[ad] == role.Manager){
            txt = "Manager";
            return;
        }
        if(roles[ad] == role.Admin){
            txt = "Admin";
            return;
        }
        return "Нет такого пользователя";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getRoleOf(adress ad)` --> `getRoleOf(address ad)`

Its spelling mistake `address`.

Answer (score -3):

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract BlackLivesMatterToken is ERC20 {
constructor(unit256 initialSupply) public ERC20("BlackLivesMatterToken", "BLM") {
_mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
}
}

Comment: you should add your code inside a code snippet and add a description